# How do I keep crawl from crawling file contents but still have the filenames and metadata appear in search?

Tags: search-results, 2016, metadata, crawling, crawl

We have about 10 million items in our webapp that we crawl. The owners created a special search page that searches the items using the search API but only searches the filename and metadata, not the contents. To speed up crawl, is there a way to keep crawl from crawling the contents of the files and only grab the filenames and metadata to populate the index with?

Answer (score 0):

There's no option as far as I'm aware. You should look at infrastructure if you're having crawl performance issues.

Comment: If we knew all the documents were PDFs, could we remove the iFilter? That would prevent crawl from crawling the content but still log the file and metadata into the index correct?